# Hadoop fs -cp , says file does not exist?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

The file new.txt is available for sure; I dunno why when I'm trying to move into directory of hdfs, it's saying file doesn't exist.

```
deepak@deepak:/$ cd $HOME/fs
deepak@deepak:~/fs$ ls
new.txt
deepak@deepak:~/fs$ cat new.txt
an apple a day keeps the doctor away
deepak@deepak:~/fs$ hadoop fs -cp $HOME/fs/new.txt $HOME/hdfs
cp: File does not exist: /home/deepak/fs/new.txt
deepak@deepak:~/fs$
```

PS: I have created a directory called hdfs already:

```
deepak@deepak:~/fs$ hadoop fs -mkdir $HOME/hdfs
mkdir: cannot create directory /home/deepak/hdfs: File exists
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[cp](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#cp)** is used when you wish to copy data from one HDFS location to another HDFS location. But you intend to copy data from your local FS to HDFS. To copy data from local FS to HDFS you can use either **[put](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#put)** or **[copyFromLocal](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#copyFromLocal)**.

If you really wish to do it using **cp** then you must specify the complete path along with the scheme. Say,

```
hadoop fs -cp file:///Users/miqbal1/date.txt /
```

**cp** by default assumes the scheme to be **hdfs://**

But why would you do that, when you have **put** and **copyFromLocal**??

HTH

Answer (score 2):

For copying files from local to hdfs, Following command should be used

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $HOME/fs/new.txt $HOME/hdfs
```

For cat hdfs file you may use the following command

```
hadoop fs -cat $HOME/hdfsnew.txt
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked perfectly!! any reason why -cp cant be used ?